# Java Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'

Tags: java

I really need help, I am new to programming. Every time i run my code I get this problem Conversion = '-'.

Here is the code:

Her is the code for Product

```
public abstract class Product implements Comparable<Product>, Serializable{
private Discount dR;
private String description;
private double price;
private int numInStock;
private Date releaseDate;
private int rating;

public Product() {

}
```

And here is the code for Discount which is dR

```
public class Discount {
private Product pro;
private Customer cust;
private double price;
private int quantity; 
private double getDiscount;
private char discountRate;

public Discount() {
    super();
}



public String toStringD() {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String string;

    string = "ALL PRODUCT SOLD";

    string = string + String.format("%-35s %-20d", description, dR.getQuantity()) + 
            "\t\t" + nf.format(price) + "\t" + String.format("%-15f %-15d", dR.getPrice(), releaseDate);
    return string;
}
```

Here is the problem

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'
```

Comment: Concatenation and formatting, eh? `str + String.format("fmt", arg1, arg2)` can be written more efficiently as `String.format("%sfmt", str, arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: Try to print the strings without left alignment first, then worry about formatting

Comment: I don't think you copied all the right values... `releaseDate` can't be printed from the Discount class

Answer (score 0):

java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'

is thrown when you try to format a string using a different type from the one that you declared in the string, ie: %d, %f, etc.

To corroborate this, i run your method in my ide changing the parameters in the string format functions for hardcoded params of the right type.

I could run your method without problems.

Therefore, either:

1) "description" is not a string.
2) dR.getQuantity() returns a float or other non-integer types.
3) dr.getPrice() doesn't return a float 
4) releaseDate doesn't return an integer.

Since you didn't provide the rest of your code I can't tell you exactly which of these is giving you trouble, but I think that with this info you can track the variable that is giving you trouble.